# macvlan and RST packets

Tags: linux, networking

I have netcat running as a listener on port 7001 this is to troubleshoot a network client.
I ran wireshark on the server to capture the packets.

If I connect using eth0, it connects fine. SYN <-> SYN/ACK

If I use eth0mv1 it fails like this: SYN <-> ACK/RST

eth0mv1 was built with:

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0mv1 type macvlan
dhclient eth0mv1
```

how do I figure this out?

update: If I set up 100 of them, the first I use works, all the rest don't

Answer (score 1):

by any chance, are all the interfaces being created with exactly the same MAC address? you should specify a separate MAC for each macvlan interface;

`ip link add link eth0 address 00:11:22:33:44:55 eth0mv1 type macvlan`

Comment: If it is called without specifying an address, a random one is generated.